# Java: enum toString()

Tags: java, string, enums

I have created an enum and I'm trying to allow my enum to support a String.format operation that gets unlimited number of parameters are return a string.
I only managed to return an object and after using this method I have to do a `toString()`/casting. I am guessing there's a more "clean" way to do it, or maybe to override better the `toString()` method. Basically, I wanted to support the `toString()` method but sadly didn't manage to do that so I created this method.  As you can see it's named `text(..)` and not `toString()`.

How can I do this better?  The ideal solution I wanted was something like `toString(..)` which returns a String.

```
public enum MY_ENUM {

    VALUE_A("aaa %s"), VALUE_B("bbb %s");

    private String text;

    MY_ENUM(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String text() {
        return this.text;
    }

    public Object text(final Object... o) {
        return new Object() {
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return String.format(text(), o);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Why make this method an instance method of an enum, since it doesn't use anything from the enum instance?

Comment: How is this method related to your enum? What do you want it to return exactly?

Comment: I extended my code, im trying to support a toString() method with few given string params..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see where you're going... I think this is what you want (tested, and it works):

```
public String toString(Object... o) {
    return String.format(text, o);
}
```

For a design point of view, I would *not* publish the text (ie have the getter) unless you really need to - the fact that `text` is used as a format string is an implementation choice. I would simply do this:

```
public static enum MY_ENUM {

    VALUE_A("aaa %s bbb %s"),
    VALUE_B("bbb %s");

    private final String text;

    MY_ENUM(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String toString(Object... o) {
        return String.format(text, o);
    }
}
```

As an aside, I really like the idea of the class. Haven't seen it before.

Comment: Great solution, works perfectly, erm, i was really close to solve it myself, thanks a lot!

Comment: I like this idea too, though I would favour using a function more like `anEnumValue.format(Object o)`. to me, 'toString' should return a string representation of the enum value itself, so `VALUE_A` would be like "aaa <object toString> bbb <objecttoString>".

Comment: @thecoshman that is true of `toString()` *without* a parameter ( ie overriding Object's impl), but `toString()` *with* parameter(s) can do what it likes. There are lots of examples from the JDK that use this pattern, for example [`Integer.toString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int)).

Comment: @Bohemian fair point, though we are of course arguing semantics here now. I'd still favour `.format(...)`  over `.toString(...)` in this context.

Answer (score 4):

You can't override `toString()` if you need to pass more parameters (`toString()` doesn't receive any). Simply define a new method in the enum, no need to override:

```
public String getAsFormattedText(Object... o) {
    return String.format(text, o);
}
```

You shouldn't name this method `toString()`, it'd be confusing because you're not returning the string representation of the current object, instead you're returning a formatted string of the objects passed as parameters. Also, the `text()` method should be called `getText()`, that's the Java convention.

Better use a name that clearly indicates that the returned string is not any string - it's a formatted string that expects the text to be formatted as a parameter - `getAsFormattedText()` clearly expresses this.

Comment: Yes very confusing when someone doesnt want to pass any params but gets the parameterless toString.